# DELL Dock station WD19S not recognized on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, dell

I'm trying to connect a Dell Dock station WD19S on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop (my goal is to connect 2 external monitors to my laptop). Under Devices list, when I plug in a USB-C cable from the Dock station to my laptop, I see that Dell dock is listed, but the `boltctl` command is giving nothing.

[image]

[image]

I installed Displaylink drivers from this site (https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu), then followed this procedure (https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0) and finally rebooted my laptop, but the Dell dock station is still not recognized.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Your question doesn't make any sense (at least to me), You state that you can see the dock is listed and then state that it's not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

These dockingstations do not use DisplayLink, but DisplayPort Alternate Mode over USB-C.  And older laptops do not support that optional mode, even if they have USB-C connectors.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you have a source for these statements?

Comment: How can I know if my computer supports "DisplayPort Alternate Mode over USB-C" ?